# Shrink memory of an array of pointers, possible?

Tags: c

I am having difficulties to find a possible solution so I decided to post my question. I am writing a program in C, and:

- i am generating a huge array containing a lot of pointers to ints, it is allocated dynamically and filled during runtime. So before I don't know which pointers will be added and how many. The problem is that they are just to many of them, so I need to shrink somehow the space.

IS there any package or tool available which could possibly encode my entries somehow or change the representation so that I save space?

Another question, I also thought about writing a file with my information, is this then kept in memory the whole time or just if I reopen the file again?

Comment: Show us what have you done so far and tell us what are the specific problems you're having with your current implementation. Read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: _"encode/change to save space"_ is too vague, IMO (especially because we don't know about what you're talking). But there is `realloc`...

Comment: How about just [reallocating](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) the array once you know the correct amount? Or reallocate while filling the array (which is quite common).

Comment: Ok sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough.
So I basically have an array like this:

int **my_adressed = malloc(sizeof(int*) * number);

And during runtime, I am adding pointers... reallocating and whatever. Abut at some point, I just have to much pointers, so my RAM is not enough to save all of them

Comment: You're going to have to post a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you allocate to much memory you have two options: One is to change your design to not need that much memory, the second option is to install more memory.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to store pointers to ints and not just the ints themselves?  If you really need them, consider making it an array of indices instead of true pointers, and having a second array of ints.  You can easily make the indices 16 or 24 bits (with a bit of extra math), or even an arbitrary number of bits (with even more math), which will be much smaller than the 32 or 64 bits required for a true int pointer.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment about redesign, you have to ask yourself if you really *need* all those pointers in memory at the same time? Once you're finished with one pointer, you can free the memory it points to and reuse the pointer.

Comment: Pointers to ints?  What is the point of that?

Comment: IF I wouldn't need all of them, I would ask how to do it

Comment: You are, presumably, aware that you have more metadata than data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for a simple dynamic array ([the advanced data type dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array), that is). There should be many implementations for this out there. You can simply start with a small dynamic array and push new items to the back just like you would do with a vector in c++ or java. One implementation would be [GArray](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Arrays.html). You will only allocate the memory you need.

If you have to/want to do it manually, the usual method is to store the capacity and the size of the array you allocated along with the pointer in a struct and call realloc() from within push_back() whenever you need more space. Usually you should increase the size of your array by a factor of 1.3 to 1.4, but a factor of 2 will do if you're not expecting a HUGE array. If you call remove and your size is below a certain threshold (e.g. capacity/2) you shrink the array again with realloc();